# Display particular nodes in a linked list java

Tags: java, list, nodes, display

my java is not great but basically i am trying to display certain nodes inside a linked list. The user picks which class they want to display the members from and it will display all users attending that class. I know how to display everything in a linked list but it's just displaying from a particular class in this case. When i press the display button it is displaying everything inside the list not just what the user picks in the combo box. Please help!!

this is just an instance of the linked list that i'm using.

```
    Booking bk = new Booking();
```

Here is my code:

```
if (event.getSource()==btnDisplay)
        {   
            Booking bk = new Booking();

            ListIterator li = bookings.listIterator();
            Boolean found = false;
            while(li.hasNext() && found==false)
            {
                bk = (Booking)li.next();
                if(bk.getLessonType()==cmbClass.getSelectedItem().toString().charAt(0))
                {

                    String s = "";

                    txtArea.setText("");
                    s="LessonType           No.InParty  Surname   Forename   InstructorCode \n";
                    txtArea.append(s);
                    s="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                    txtArea.append(s);

                    Iterator i = bookings.iterator();

                    while(i.hasNext())
                    {
                        s = i.next().toString();

                        txtArea.append(s);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```